# PHP - Remove Apostrophe from POST varible

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have created a form in PHP and MySQL. After submitting the data, it is saved into the MySQL table. But I have got a problem: If the form contains an apostrophe then there will be an error while inserting the data, so how can i remove the apostrophe from the post variable?

```
$description=$_POST['description'];
```

Comment: You don't remove it, you escape it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver how can i escape it?

Comment: See my answer dude, I amended it.

Comment: @BillyJakeO'Connor what does msql_real_escape_string() will do?

Comment: It stops characters from breaking mySql statements, such as your apostrophe http://uk3.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape characters, to stop them from breaking your SQL statements. I recommend you read up on SQL injections. I think this is taken care of automatically in the mySQLi extension, which you should be using as this method is depreciated nowadays.

```
 $descrtion = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
```